# Magento 2 website varnish x-varnish-age = 0

Tags: magento2.4, varnish

When I refresh page and check the header of homepage I got this below information where `x-varnish-age=0`
[image]
Want to confirm if there is an issue with cacheable="false"? If any block on page is `cacheable="false"` so it causes  `x-varnish-age=0` for that page ? If yes if I have to make some block noncacheable, what should I do to make page varnish cacheable ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that there's a `Set-Cookie` header in your response. That will cause Varnish to mark this incoming response as uncacheable because it changes the state.

If the next request for this resource doesn't return a response that contains the `Set-Cookie` header, you'll be fine and Varnish will store the object in the cache.

If every request returns a `Set-Cookie` header, the page will never end up in the cache.

As yourself why this cookie needs to be set and if this happens only once?

If you're looking for more information on Varnish and Magento, please have a look at the following article: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/